# Create Access databases programatically through vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, ado.net

Let me preface this by saying that I know this is a stupid way to go about this, but it needs to be handled in this way.

I need to make an application that from a master database creates a number of access database files (tables of a larger db), then these are manually given to users who fill in data, the database files are emailed back to a user who, through the application, combines them again.

The only part of this that I am unsure about is problematically creating the access db's. I have read that through Microsoft Jet OLE DB Provider and Microsoft ADO Ext I can create them (the tables and data), but I also need forms.

I have yet to start writing anything and this is away from my area of work, so any insight/links would be much appreciated.

Also, I would hope to be able to write this in the free express version of visual studio. Are there components needed that would prevent me from this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you are developing in vb.net then why do you need forms in the Access database? Create a vb.net application for the "client" pcs with the required forms reading and writing to the Access database.

If however you do need to have forms in an Access database. Create a database with the required forms and code. Distribute the code/form database and the data database. Add a method to the code/form database the creates links to the tables in the "data" database.